# Is there any way to handle native send of outlook appointment from add-in through Office.js?

Tags: office365api, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

To get Item Id in appointment compose mode i am using "saveAsync" in add-in  the problem is with out user intervention the appointment  item is saving to the MS Exchange.After discarding the opened appointment (by using office cancel "X" button) still the changes which i made while "saveAsync" execution are presented, it's not regaining the previous state.

I need to know is there any way to bring back the previous state of appointment if user click on discard ?
                             (OR)
Any way to handle the native send of outlook appointment from add-in through the office.js after "saveAsync" got applied ?
                             (OR)
Is there any other way of getting the Item Id of appointment in compose mode through the Office.js ?

Please,answer if you know how to handle any of these cases.

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Did Microsoft support handling native send of outlook appointment from add-in ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Looks like at this time, it is not possible to revert to last saved version via the add-in, nor is there any way to get the itemId without `saveAsync`

Old Answer

*If you are modifying an existing appointment, you can get the ItemID by calling `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId`, however if you are creating a new appointment, you must call `saveAsync` in order for your appointment to be registered, and thereby given an ItemId.*

Comment: Thanks Andrew, As a organizer i opened an existing appointment  and tried to get the ItemID as you said by using **Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId** still it's undefined. as per my understanding Office.js considering that if organizer opened existing appointment or newly creating appointment the mode is compose mode and **itemId** not defined for that Item.
I can get the itemId by saveAsync but state is saving without user intervention on the office view. that's on my question. how to handle these scenarios.

Comment: You are correct. ItemId appears to not be available in compose mode, this was an oversight on my part. With that said, it appears that there is no way to get the itemId of a compose item without saveAsync